# Display an image icon on a jqPlot

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I would like to know if it is possible to display an image at a specified coordinates in a jqplot graph.
I am currently using jqplot to display a graph. I would like to display a specific image at some desired location on the plot.

Thanks,
RVK

Answer (score 0):

I found this, which may be useful to you. It enables plotting images on the graph: https://github.com/heminm/JQPlot-Image-Renderer